# subview frame of UITextfiled in uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, ios7

I am adding the  TextField in UIScrollview on  Add button click event, I want to show the last textfield frame and to show in UIScrollview .

MyCode :- `[scrollview convertRect:subview.frame toView:someOtherView];`

[image: ScreenShot]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Adjust your scrollview position

Comment: i want  to display the last textfiled frame click on add buttton

Comment: can you be more specific...

Comment: @Rajneesh071 when i click on add then texfiled added so i want to get that frame of uitextfiled

Comment: whats the code inside addBtn click

Comment: [scrollview addsubview:txtFiled];

Comment: @Rushabh you want above the picture output is it?

Comment: @Rushabh which viewcontroller has been added your scrollview with same one or different

Comment: @iDev same view controller

Comment: Hey I am also facing similar issue. Once we add anything in scrollview then we try to get frame of object after adding into scrollview then its give some different frame.

Comment: did you get any issue

Comment: its returns me  CGRectMake(0,0,150,30).

Comment: @Nirmit  because the scrollview frame is changing every time when ever you have to add new textfield

Comment: Hey I found the solution of it. Please check my answer. Its work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[scrView layoutSubviews];
```

We just have to set layoutSubview for scrollview and its works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers in your list are going to stay evenly spaced, you should probably be using a UITableView.  It is easy to implement UITableViewDataSource to manage its rows, and it provides animation for free.  UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView so you could use the same `setContentOffset` method, but it's cleaner to use index paths.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] inSection:0];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
```